# android socket connection through a new activity

Tags: android, sockets, android-activity

I am trying to open a new "activity" (C2M) in an Android app, and in that new activity open a socket with the ip address and port coming from the previous "activity" (called MeasActivity).
I have checked that the ip and address are correctly gotten in C2M (as strings), but the socket can not be created.
Part of the code is the following:

```
public class C2M extends Activity {
    Socket socket;
    private String serverIpAddress;
    private String serverPort;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmeas);
        intentback = new Intent(this, MeasActivity.class);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        serverIpAddress = intent.getStringExtra(MeasActivity.EXTRA_IP);
        serverPort = intent.getStringExtra(MeasActivity.EXTRA_PORT);
        try {
            socket = new Socket(serverIpAddress, Integer.parseInt(serverPort));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            startActivity(intentback);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the manifest file is the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MeasActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="C2M"></activity>
</application>
```

I am not sure if I missing something, but as I said, I have issues creating the socket.

Thanks in advance for the help and advice you can provide.

gus

Comment: What do you mean with the stackTrace? Thanks.

Comment: Just solved the problem setting the opening of the socket in a new thread... just if someone is interested about that....